# Окно SDL под всеми окнами

Tags: c++, linux, sdl2, x11

Мне нужно расположить окно, созданное с помощью SDL2 под всеми окнами (Linux, X11)
Пробовал таким способом - не работает

```
Atom belowState = XInternAtom(xDisplay, "_NET_WM_STATE_BELOW", false);
Atom prop = XInternAtom(xDisplay, "_NET_WM_STATE", false);
XChangeProperty(xDisplay, xWindow, prop, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char*)&belowState, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);

Window xWindow = wmInfo.info.x11.window;
Atom netWmState = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
Atom belowState = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE_BELOW", False);

XChangeProperty(display, xWindow, netWmState, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&belowState, 1);

XCloseDisplay(display);
```